# Firebase / Android - Esperar todos los thread para un Handle

Tags: android, firebase, hilos, response

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public synchronized void next(final RoomListQueryResultHandler handler) {
        this.setLoading(true);

        roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
        this.database.child("members").child(this.mUser.getUid()).child("rooms")
                .limitToFirst(this.mLimit)
                .startAt(this.currentPage * this.mLimit)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        RoomListQuery.this.setLoading(false);
                        //mListAdapter.setLoading(false);

                        if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                            RoomListQuery.this.currentPage--;
                        }
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Room room = ds.getValue(Room.class);
                            //roomList.add(Room.upsert(room));
                            Room.getRoom(room.getId(), new Room.RoomGetHandler() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(Room room, customException e) {
                                    if (e != null) {
                                        // Error!
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    roomList.add(room);
                                }
                            });
                            handler.onResult(roomList, (customException) null);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        handler.onResult((List) null, new customException(databaseError.toString()));
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Si se fijan tengo dos Handler, al principio llamo a una lista de "rooms" desde Firebase, y luego por cada una voy a consultar el detalle.

El problema que tengo es que la respuesta me la da vacia, ya que no espera que se  ejecuten todos los for para el detalle de las "rooms", por lo cual la variable roomList siempre vuelve vacia.

Alguna idea de que puedo implementar, o que otra metodologia utilizar para poder resolverlo?

Muchas gracias!
Saludos.

============== Edito ============

Le agregue un contador para saber en que momento hacerle el callback.

```
public synchronized void next(String key,final RoomListQueryResultHandler handler) {

        this.setLoading(true);
        roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
        this.database.child("members").child(this.mUser.getUid()).child("rooms")
                .orderByKey()
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        RoomListQuery.this.setLoading(false);
                        if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                            RoomListQuery.this.currentPage--;
                        }

                        // at the start we need to still load all children
                        final long[] pendingLoadCount = { dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() };

                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            //roomList.add(Room.upsert(room));
                            Room.getRoom(ds.getKey(), new Room.RoomGetHandler() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(Room room, customException e) {
                                    if (e != null) {
                                        // Error!
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    roomList.add(room);

                                    // we loaded a child, check if we're done
                                    pendingLoadCount[0] = pendingLoadCount[0] - 1;
                                    if (pendingLoadCount[0] == 0) {
                                        if (handler != null) {
                                            Friends.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    handler.onResult(roomList, (customException) null);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }


                                }
                            });

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(final DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        if (handler != null) {
                            Friends.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    handler.onResult((List) null, new customException(databaseError.toString()));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No queda del todo claro que hace Room.getRoom y por que no usar el room que está almacenado en Firebase. Pero si lo que querés es bloquear el hilo hasta que se terminen todas las consultas hay 2 alternativas:

1) Si tu tarea extiende [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) del [API de tareas de Google Play](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) (recomendado) , puedes usar el método `Tasks.whenAll(<colección de tareas>)` , el cual bloquea el hilo actual hasta que todas las tareas asíncronas en la colección terminen (exitosamente o no).

2) Si `Room.getRoom` es una tarea que no puede incorporar el API de tareas, puedes optar por [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) que es una clase estándar de Java que tiene un contador y bloquea el hilo hasta que el contador llega a cero (deberías decrementar el contador cada vez que una tarea se complete).

Comment: Hola @jirungaray, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo ajuste agregando un contador y esperando que este en cero para devolver el callback. Lo ves correcto o es mejor las alternativas que planteaste?

Comment: me parece bien, es una buena alternativa. Por favor marca la pregunta como respondida para que otras personas puedan usar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien como va el proceso pero entiendo que quieres primero obtener la lista y luego usar esa lista en el handler.

Yo lo que haría sería implementar un callback para que cuando termine de traer toda la información desde firebase pueda "avisar" al handler de la finalización de la operación y así te aseguras que la lista nunca va a estar vacía.